# Source of phrase "tizkeh l'mitzvos"

Tags: sources-mekorot, mitzvah, social-convention

I have noticed that when I give money to people who collect in shul, they often respond by saying "tizkeh l'mitzvos."

Are there any sources before relatively recently for using this phrase?

Comment: I think the phrase is "tizku l'mitzvos."

Comment: @ezra tizku is plural of tizke

Comment: To clarify, are you just looking for examples of this being used in speech as a blessing, or are you looking for any source that refers to having the zekhut of performing a mitsvah?

Comment: @mevaqesh I would like a source for such a phrase, in terms of the actual bracha, i'm fine with it

Comment: 1. חשוקי חמד תוכן העניינים על הגמרא
  . האם מותר לומר תודה או תזכו למצוות לאחר ההלוואה [ב"מ עה ע"ב]1982. האם מותר 
2. עלי תמר שקלים פרק ב
   שאם אדם נותן תרומה של צדקה המקבל אומר תזכה למצוות או תזכו למצוות. ונראה שהמקור הוא בויק"ר פל"ד אות ז, אמר ר"ז אפילו שיחה של בני א"י תורה, כיצד אדם אומר לחברו זכי בי. וביטוי זה ...

Comment: 3. שו"ת מנחת שלמה חלק א סימן כז
  מופע ראשון: לו הודיעני אם בא איש פלוני ממקום פלוני, ולפיכך כתבו האחרונים דה"ה נמי שלא יאמר הלוה למלוה "תודה", ורבים נוהגים משום כך לומר במקום זה "תזכו למצוות" ולענ"ד לא יפה הם עושים כי תזכו למצוות הוא ממש ברכה והיינו רבית דברים כמו"ש התוס' בקדושין ח' ע"ב בד"ה צדקה, ואילו אמירת ...

Comment: While I'm not suggesting that this is the source of the adage, but there seems to be support from 2 areas I can consider - 1) Pirkei Avot (forgot exact location) that says that one mitzvah merits another, or a similar one there saying that the reward of a mitzvah is another mitzvah, or 2) The Gemarah (or Midrash?) that translates "Aser Te'aser" (giving tithes) as "Aser kedei shetitasher" - Tithe in order that you will become rich. That one seems to be related more to giving tzedaka.

Comment: Now that I think more about it, I wonder if this is a subtle hidden form of "self advertising"? I.e., you did the mitzvah of giving tzedaka. "Tizke lemitzvot" may be their way of saying, subtly, that "You should merit another opportunity that when I see you again next time (and that could be later in the day!) you will be able to give me tzedaka again!"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know when common usage of this phrase began. However, from reading various articles, it appears to have been in common usage for many decades. [This article](https://www.wisetemple.org/study/rabbis-blog/tizku-lmitzvahpay-it-foward/) seems to support the notion that at least the concept supporting the expression is from [Pirkei Avot 4:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53085&st=&pgnum=50) where Ben Azai says that one should be careful to perform every "type" of mitzvah - both "easy" and "difficult" ones, because one mitzvah "pulls" (or instigates) another mitzvah, and the reward of a mitzvah is (another) mitzvah.

Rav Bartenura, in his commentary, explains the concept of the "reward" part, in that when one performs a mitzvah, in heaven, another mitzvah is prepared for that person so that the person may receive reward for both of them.

So, I gather that the idea behind the wish "tizkeh lemitzvot" is in line with Rav Bartenura's explanation. When you give tzedaka (though, the wish is not limited to hearing this from tzedaka recipients), the person is using the plural form "mitzvoth" as a hint that you should merit to be able to perform another mitzvah and receive the reward for both the tzedaka giving as well as the next mitzvah.